# A line tangent to a circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ at $x=2$

Tags: circles, tangent-line

The question stated that the line has a positive gradient, tangent to the line at $x=2$,

Is it even possible? 
Since if the line tangent at $x=2$ means it has negative gradient.

Let's make another circle perpendicular to the previous line, that line is y2=x, it has a positive gradient, makes the line tangent to the circle y1 has a negative gradient.

It is impossible for y2 to have negative gradient, because it must goes to (0,0)(2,2) to be perpendicular to y1..

Where was i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a line with positive gradient which touches the circle at $x=2$. That means the circle must have a point $(2,y)$ which means that $r\ge2$. So assume that is true. Draw a picture.

[image]

Can you finish? What happens if $r=2$?

Comment: I added on the question, r =8, and to touches x=2, y1 has a negative gradient

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Fine. So what is the equation of the required tangent?

Comment: y=4-x ? Goes to (2,2) gradient -1

Comment: @Lifeforbetter (1) you need to get the tangent at $B$, not $A$; (2) if the circle has radius 8, what are the coordinates of point $B$?

Comment: B(2,-2) so y1 = x - 4 ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter If $(2,\pm2)$ are on the circle then its radius is $\sqrt8$ not $8$. But suppose that is the case. Then yes, the radius $OB$ would have gradient -1, so the tangent should have gradient 1, so its equation would be $y-x=4$. However, if you really want $r=8$, then the circle is $x^2+y^2=64$, so $x=2$ gives ...